# How do you handle file uploads in a google cloud hosted website?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm experimenting with the google cloud platform, and the app engine. I have published a relatively simple website with a cms attached, part of which allows a user to upload images.  As there doesn't seem to be a way to FTP to the site, or manage files like that, is there a "google cloud" way of managing these particular files?  The user would need to be able to upload files, and see what files have already been uploaded (it doesn't seem like a complex requirement, but I can't see how one would manage it with the app engine)

Comment: This question does not have a simple answer. There are many ways to upload files. In the old days, files were upload using HTTP POST directly to the web server. In the cloud, an improved method is to use Cloud Storage. There are lots of articles on the Internet discussing the various techniques with pros/cons and implementation details.

Comment: @JohnHanley To try and clear it up, it's more about where the files are stored (typically in a folder on the site). with no way to access those files (ftp) then what's the GPC way to do it?

Comment: Google Cloud is not involved in the process of users uploading files to your web server other than possible security or bandwidth issues. It is completely up to your software to manage the entire process including where files are stored.